# Getting the string between specified pattern PHP

Tags: php, preg-match

I have string like this

```
$string = "<!--:en-->English Characters<!--:--><!--:zh-->日本<!--:-->";
```

I'm only interested with the content between `<!--:zh--><!--:-->`;

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
preg_match( '/<!--:zh-->(.*?)<!--/', $string, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
```

Comment: We are very near I think but the result includes `日本<!--:`

Comment: your edit and this works also  `'/<!--:zh-->(.*?)<!--:-->/'`  thanks